# Neo4j Load CSV without Local Admin privileges

Tags: neo4j, load-csv

I'm trying to evaluate Neo4j-Community-3.2.2 and my IT department installed the product for me in an area where I have no permissions. All I have seem to have is a running Service and the client interface through the browser. I have an immediate problem with LOAD CSV, but I anticipate others.

My current problem is that LOAD CSV seems to limit me to the Import folder under the database, which is in a protected location. I cannot copy files to the Neo4j import directory. I need to point the location to a folder I own.

I read in a different post that this is a security measure. So .. IF there is no way to address another folder, is there a configuration option that would let me work around. I can engage my IT department to edit / replace a config file, I think.

It would be best to implement a configuration setting to point to an entirely different Neo4j root. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

> [dbms.directories.import](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/configuration-settings/#config_dbms.directories.import)
>
> Sets the root directory for file URLs used with the Cypher LOAD CSV
>   clause. This must be set to a single directory, restricting access to
>   only those files within that directory and its subdirectories.

So just point the full path to the directory in the `neo4j.conf` where you can place the files:

```
dbms.directories.import = /path/to/csv/import/directory
```

Note that the user under which the `neo4j` is started must have permission to read files from this directory.